# Do WPF hyperlinks only work in pages?

Tags: wpf, hyperlink

I'm new to the `Hyperlink` control. I wish to have a hyperlink in a regular WPF window which will navigate to a URL by opening the standard browser. I have added the hyperlink, but it does nothing.

Before I implement a handler to do the work myself, can anyone please confirm that the Hyperlink control will navigate only within pages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You [will need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.navigateuri.aspx) to do it yourself.

The simplest way to do it is to handle the [Hyperlink.RequestNavigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.requestnavigate.aspx) event and call [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) with the URL.  (This will open the default browser).

Comment: I would just add that if you plan on having several hyperlinks in your application that it would be wise to handle the Hyperlink.RequestNavigate event as a routed event rather than hook the event on every single Hyperlink instance.